# How can I connect two piezoelectric sensors in Proteus?

Tags: arduino, proteus, piezo

I'm having a problem on my project. I connected two piezoelectric sensors together in parallel, but when I run the simulation on virtual terminal, the reading shows that it only using one piezoelectric sensor whose value is 784. Any solution?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: How would the virtual terminal know how many sensors your MCU has connected or how many of them are in parallel? What do you expect to see and why?

Answer (score 1):

From the picture, I assume you are using [this library.](https://github.com/satyamkr80/PiezoElectric-Sensor-Library-For-Proteus)

As far as I can tell, the "sensor" doesn't actually sense anything, and there's not any way to input signals to it.

At most, it looks like there's a custom symbol to represent the part in the diagram and that in the background it has a simple capacitor simulation.

It's pretty much a dummy.  It doesn't matter how many of them you put in your circuit, they won't do anything.

---

That thing looks to have been hacked together from some other custom library.  It is full of references to GPS receivers and serial ports with only a few lines at the end of the file referring to the piezo sensor.

Comment: I see. So the sensor module is just a dummy and cant really give me the accurate value output voltage that the piezoelectric sensor can give. Do you have any solution on how can I do a simulation on the piezoelectric sensor on Proteus

Comment: Where would you expect it to get a value to give you in the simulation?  What signal are you expecting to get from a piezoelectric disc?

Comment: I was planning on using 6 piezoelectric sensor with parallel connection that will generate 3V for each sensor. So, basically  by using 6 piezoelectric sensor, it will produce (18VAC). Is it possible to do the simulation on proteus?

Comment: If it did work, it'd destroy the Arduino ADC input.  18V is way outside the Arduino's input range.  The value you are getting indicates a DC voltage from the "sensor," not AC.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Oh actually this piezoelectric sensor output voltage is suppose to be converted into DC voltage by using full bridge rectifier. The arduino got nothing to do with my project. I was just trying to connect the sensor to the MCU and read the value from virtual terminal

Comment: My project is to convert vibration energy from into electrical energy by using piezoelectric sensor and convert the signal from AC to DC to power up a device. I am using the proteus to run a simulation but the reading from the piezoelectric sensor is not accurate even when I connect with multiple piezoelectric sensor

Comment: Forget the simulation.  Get some piezo discs of the type you intend to use and hook them up to an oscilloscope.  Put various resistors in parallel with the piezo as it is generating power - notice that a smaller value resistor will lower the voltage.  Calculate the generated power and energy from the voltage measured with the scope and the value of the resistor.

Comment: @Kcjcjxjxjx:  Piezoelectric devices only output a voltage as a result of bending or stressing the sensor - a simulator program can't simulate that bending effect.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to run a simulation on what connection of piezoelectric sensor is suitable to generate the highest output voltage before doing the project. Is it parallel connection or series and I need to get the output voltage generated by every connection

Comment: The most reasonable way is to convert the output of each piezo to DC.